# PHP Cookie conditionals not working

Tags: php, cookies

I am getting **syntax error, unexpected T_IF** error:

```
<div id="notification-container">
<div id="notification">'.if(isset($_COOKIE['HotspotUserEmail'])){$m01}else{$m03}.'<div id="secondary">'.$m04.'</div>
</div></div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is, if the cookie is present I want to show the text contained in **$m01**, but if it isn't I want **$m03** to show.

Am I missing something/doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Use a ternary operator! I also assume that you print these strings.

Comment: Is the HTML code inside or outside the <?php tag?